# How to change text on individual jquery slider handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery range slider that I am using to select a percentage of color for an overall image and it can have a dynamic number of handles based on how many elements the user decides to use.  I am trying to display the percentage for each of the individual handles of the slider in the handles themselves.  I have not had luck in figuring this one out and I'm hoping to get some help/direction.

I have found a number of examples on the net that have selected the ".ui-slider-handle" and then modified the text but I can only seem to get this to change one or all of them to the same text. I also got the slider object and then got its children, then iterated through the children and tried changing the text val for each but it never changes it. Any ideas?

This doesn't work:

```
myslider.slider({                    
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  orientation: 'vertical',
  values: handles,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var handleText = $(this)[0].children[0].text;
    handleText = "Test";
    console.log("val should be changed: ",handleText);

    //The below line works, however it changes them all to the same value                   
    //myslider.find("a.ui-slider-handle").text(ui.values);

  }
});
```

Comment: Your code is simply reassigning the value of `handleText`, not changing the text itself.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and when possible, a jsFiddle.net example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer:** You can use `each()` to do what you want (and here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wgE5/7/)):

```
myslider.find("a.ui-slider-handle").each(function( index ) {
     $(this).text(ui.values[index]);
});
```

Let's break it down:

1. `myslider.find("a.ui-slider-handle")` - get all the handle objects, just like you're doing right now.
2. `.each(function( index ) {` - apply a function to *each* element that we just found, using its index in the jQuery object as an argument.  `each()` is what's doing the heavy lifting; more on it [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
3. `$(this).text(ui.values[index]);` - make *this* handle's text the value from our `values` object that corresponds to this handle's `index`.
4. `});` - close up the shop.

That should do the trick!

Note: `myslider.find("a.ui-slider-handle").text(ui.values);` didn't work because, while it selected all the correct handles, it just assigned them one value - your `values` sequence.  You need to use the above method to break up the contents of `values` and apply them to the handles separately.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking when I assigned to the variable that I was getting a reference to it and it would assign to that reference.  The above didnt work but it is probably somethign stupid I'm doing.  To better illustrate, I have posted somethign similar on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4wgE5/4/

Comment: @user931341 I realized that what I thought was the problem (and was *a* problem), wasn't the real issue.  The real issue was that you were applying the same text to all of the elements.  You can do what you want using `each()`, as my updated answer explains.

Comment: ASGM you are awesome!!  Thanks so much!  I've been messing with this for the past three days and so happy there was an answer.  Thanks again!